# Create a Static Google Chrome Desktop Icon in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

Is there an easy way to make it so the Google Chrome icon on the desktop cannot be deleted? I want it to appear just like Internet Explorer does by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy the shortcut onto the 'All Users' desktop, this will prevent deletion from non-admin accounts.

If you want to remove the arrows from shortcuts, open the registry editor and navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Scroll on down to `Pifile`. In the right pane, rename `ISSHORTCUT` to read `SHORTCUT`.

### Update

I just tried the method from your link in XP and it works just fine.

Copy the following code and paste it into a Notepad:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}]
@="Google Chrome"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Documents and Settings\\USER\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}\Shell]
@="Open"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}\Shell\Open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}\Shell\Open\Command]
@="C:\\Documents and Settings\\USER\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}\ShellEx]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=hex:00,00,00,00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}]
```

note: replace USER with your account name! (Windows 7 requires additional changes to the path, just find chrome.exe, remember: double backslash!)

save the file as REG file, e.g. `chromestaticicon.reg` and import it, press F5 to refresh the desktop.

[image]

*Warning: always backup your registry before making changes!*

However, this is **not** safe from deletion, anyone with access to the registry can nuke the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0011C78C-4B81-41d2-80F5-3D992DD9ACC7}` and the Icon is gone again. :)

Comment: Ah, this is very helpful but I'd like it to be integrated with the OS - something like this:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=182427

Comment: @kirkouimet - updated my post accordingly, now i'm off to overwrite the VBox image to throughly get rid of this browser! :D

Comment: @kirkouimet - you're more than welcome. usually i'm dealing with adverse problem: how to get rid of such icons (HP used to create such desktop icons for some of their printer software :)